# What is the value of await awaitable_object?

Tags: python, async-await

I've been using generator based coroutines before the `asyncio` was released.

Now I'm trying to learn the new `async/await` features introduced in Python 3.5. This is one of my test programs.

```
class Await3:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __await__(self):
        return iter([self.value, self.value, self.value])

async def main_coroutine():
    x = await Await3('ABC')
    print("x =", x)

def dummy_scheduler(cobj):
    snd = None
    try:
        while True:
            aw = cobj.send(snd)
            #snd = 42
            print("got:", aw)
    except StopIteration:
        print("stop")

dummy_scheduler(main_coroutine())
```

Its output is:

```
got: ABC
got: ABC
got: ABC
x = None
stop
```

The value of `x` is the result of `await awaitable_object` expression. Why is this value `None` and how can I set it to a value I want?

All I could find is that value of `await couroutine()` is determined by the coroutine's return value, but that's not my case.

Uncommenting `snd = 42` does not work. The error is `AttributeError: 'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'send'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to implement a class with an `__await__` method manually, the return value of an `await` expression on an instance of your class will be whatever argument was used to construct the `StopIteration` exception at the end of the iterator, or `None` if there was no argument.

You can't control the `StopIteration` argument with something like `return iter(some_list)`. You need to write your own iterator. I'd say to write it as a generator and `return` the value:

```
class Await3:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __await__(self):
        yield self.value
        yield self.value
        yield self.value
        return whatever
```

which will throw `StopIteration(whatever)` to end the iteration, but if you wanted to do things the easy way, you would have written an `async` function in the first place.